# React Callservice script doesn't retrieve the needed information from Node.js script that makes the API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

I'm trying to make a simple webpage using React.js to display information retrieved from an API. I say simple because it should be, but I haven't developed anything for a long time and I seem to have an issue that I can't find the cause off.

I made a node.js file to act as a mediator between my webpage and the API because I was having CORS issues.

Situation:

Whenever I push the button I don't retrieve any information. The call keeps displaying "pending" as status within the network tab(see below image).
[image]

But within my Node.js script I can see by logging that I do get the correct response and retrieve all the information I need. So I can state that my node script works as it should.

I think the issue is situated between the exchange from my Node.js script and the CallService.js script. I just can't put my finger on what is wrong.

What am I missing here?

I've provided all the code I have below but left out sensitive information.

Node.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');

const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  next();
});

app.get('/ListAllModels', (req, res) => {
  request(
    {
      url: '/* api url*/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'X-Tenant-ID': '/*tenant id*/',
        'Authorization': 'Basic /*authorization*/'
      }
    },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }

      console.log(response);
     return response;
    }
  )
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on ${PORT}`));
```

I made a Callservice.js file in my react app:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const getAllEmailModels = () => {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:4000/ListAllModels").then(response => {
       if (response.statusCode === 200) {
        return response;
       }
    throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
    }).catch(error => {
        return error;
      });;
  };
```

In my app I made a button that should call on the API and provide the retrieved information in console.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
//import axios from 'axios';
import * as CallService from "../Services/CallService";


export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {emailModels:[]};
    
        this.emailModelTest = this.emailModelTest.bind(this);
      }


      emailModelTest() {
          console.log("button works");
        CallService.getAllEmailModels().then(response => this.setState({
            emailModels:  response.body,
        }), console.log(this.state.emailModels) );

        
    }


    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
            <button onClick={this.emailModelTest}>test call</button>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in here:

```
app.get('/ListAllModels', (req, res) => {
  request(
    {
      url: '/* api url*/',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'X-Tenant-ID': '/*tenant id*/',
        'Authorization': 'Basic /*authorization*/'
      }
    },
    (error, response, body) => {
      if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
        return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: err.message });
      }

      console.log(response);
     return response;
    }
  )
});
```

It's pending because it there is never a response.
When it goes to your 'ListAllModels' endpoint, it makes a request to another endpoint asynchronously.
When the response comes back it isn't inside the `app.get` function anymore.

Also, the `return response` will return the response to the caller of that callback which is inside the `request()` function. You need to send the response back to your `CallService` using the `res` object.

You could wrap it in a promise.

You need to send the response using the `res` object that is passed in as a parameter. That object represents the response send by the node server.  The only way the client can get anything is if you send something through that object using `res.send(data)`.  Using `return response;` doesn't work because it's inside another function.  It will be returned to the caller of that function not the parent function `app.get()`

```
app.get('/ListAllModels', (req, res) => {
    fetch('{{url}}', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
        'X-Tenant-ID': '{{tenant-ID}}',
        'Authorization': 'Basic {{auth}}'
      }
    }).then(otherRes => {
      res.status(200).send(otherRes);
    }).error(error => {
        res.status(400).end();
    });
});
```

Comment: ```app.get('/ListAllModels', (req, res) => {
(async () => {
  await fetch( '{{url}}',{
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
      'X-Tenant-ID': '{{tenant-ID}}',
      'Authorization': 'Basic {{auth}}'
    }}).then(res => {return res});
console.log(res);

})();

});```

Comment: @imkeVr i fixed your comment a little bit in my answer.  If you send the other response directly, the client will get a response wrapped in a response so you will need to fix that.

Comment: @imkeVr Did you figure it out?